# How will the readResolve() method of the proxy class get called in the Serialization Proxy pattern?

Tags: java, serialization, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am studying up on *Serialization Proxy* pattern. It basically says to have a a proxy class that should be declared as a static nested class of the enclosing class that we want to serialize. So the basic idea is that the proxy shields the enclosing serializable class from perils of Serialization.

However the implementation isn't actually clear to me . Why do we call the `writeReplace()` on the outer class and the `readResolve()` on the proxy class? Since the proxy class is like a *static member* of the outer class how will it even get serialized? If it does not get serialized then how will the readResolve() be called on the proxy during deserialization?

I am sure I am missing something basic here. Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation of [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

`writeReplace()` and `readResolve()` are special methods called by serialization engine.

`writeReplace()` replaces object being serialized with the proxy, and `readResolve()` replaces deserialized proxy with the actual object.

Serialization proxy class doesn't have to be a static nested class of the class you want to serialize. It's just a convention for better organization of code.

Comment: so you are saying that `readResolve()` on the proxy is called by the serialization engine only because during before serialization of the enclosing class the `writeReplace()` on it was called and that `writeReplace()` returned the proxy?

Comment: +1 for the last line that the proxy doesn't necessarily have to be a static nested class.